# Windows batch file to deploy all the dlls in a folder to GAC

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file, post-build

I'm working on an ASP.NET project where I've a bunch of dlls created in a folder. I need to write a cmd or bat file to take all the dlls in that folder and GACUTIL it. So how can loop all the dlls in a folder?

Comment: Use a `FOR` loop. Run `FOR /?` for all the gory details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I am using to deploy all sql files in a given folder, you could adjust it to act on dll files if needs be;

```
@echo off

SET dbodir=../Schema Objects/Schemas/dbo/Programmability/Stored Procedures/
SET tpmdir=../Schema Objects/Schemas/TPM/Programmability/Stored Procedures/

echo --- Starting dbo schema

for %%f in ("%dbodir%*.sql") do (echo Running %%f.... && @sqlcmd -U %1 -P %2 -S %3 -d %4 -i "%dbodir%%%f")

echo --- Completed dbo schema

echo --- Starting TPM schema

for %%g in ("%tpmdir%*.sql") do (echo Running %%g.... && @sqlcmd -U %1 -P %2 -S %3 -d %4 -i "%tpmdir%%%g")

echo --- Completed TPM schema

pause
```

Comment: No probs. I got the answer from stackoverflow in the first place :)

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is looking for the powershell way of doing it.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")            
$publish = New-Object System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish       

$dlls = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Code\Application\ -Filter *dll -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -Force  | %{$_.FullName}

 foreach ($dll in $dlls) {
   $publish.GacInstall($dll)
 }
```